# Counting average on list<T> field

Tags: c#, .net, iterator, average, mean

I have list of A, and I want to count average on it's field a.
What's the best way to do it?

```
class A
{
    int a;
    int b;
}
void f()
{
    var L = new List<A>();
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        L.Add(new A(){a = i});
    }
}
```

Comment: [Enumerable.Average](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548874%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX)

Answer (score 33):

[`Enumerable.Average`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548874%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) has an overload that takes a `Func<T, int>` as an argument.

```
using System.Linq;

list.Average(item => item.a);
```

Comment: @D Stanley, why Select() is not good in this case? any disadvantage in terms of performance?

Comment: @Sheen Although in most cases it won't be noticeable, there is a slight perf hit because you've added another enumerator on top of average's enumerator. That's an extra level of indirection. But the main problem is: you don't need it. Calling methods that you don't need hinders readability and increases complexity at best. If you had a big chain of linq method calls, adding needless `Selects` in between would make your eyes bleed.

Answer (score 5):

You could try this one:

```
var average = ListOfA.Select(x=>x.a).Average();
```

where `ListOfA` is a List of objects of type `A`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Enumerable.Average`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.average.aspx)

```
var average = L.Select(r => r.a).Average();
```