# How to calculate the average of an element in the array (salary) in C#

Tags: c#

what else do I need to add or change to display my employees between the ages of 25 and 35
years with a higher salary than average salary. This program only displays employees between the ages of 25 and 35.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < employeename; i++)
         {
            while (br.PeekChar() != -1)
            {
                function[i].Name= br.ReadString();
                function[i].Function= br.ReadString();
                function[i].Age= br.ReadInt32();
                function[i].salary= br.ReadInt32();
                function[i].Studies= br.ReadString();

                if ((function[i].Age>25) && (function[i].Age<35))
                {
                    string str = String.Format("|{0,-21}|{1,-9}|{2,-7}|{3,-16}|{4,-12}|", function[i].Name, function[i].Function,
                        function[i].Age.ToString(), function[i].Salary.ToString(), function[i].Studies);
                    Console.WriteLine(str);
                }

            }

        }
        Console.ReadKey();
        br.Close();
```

Comment: What is average salary? It sounds like an input parameter, not something you have to calculate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting average on list<T> field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386928/counting-average-on-listt-field)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to read all data and calculate avgSalary before filtering:

> Map your data in an Employee class with params Name, Function, Age,
>   Salary, Studies.

```
    var employees = new List<Employee>();
    while (br.PeekChar() != -1)
    {
        var employee = new Employee() {
           Name= br.ReadString(),
           Function= br.ReadString(),
           Age= br.ReadInt32(),
           Salary= br.ReadInt32(),
           Studies= br.ReadString()
         };
         employees.Add(employee);
     }

var avgSalary = employees.Select(x => x.Salary).Average();

var finalList = employees.Where(x => x.Age > 25 && x.Age < 35 && x.Salary > avgSalary).ToList();
```

You need to use EF & LINQ for that.

Comment: thanks. updated answer. I have not been sure about this

Comment: No need for the Select either : _"var avgSalary = employees.Average(x => x.Salary);"_

Comment: That was just nitpicking. But here is the method signature `public static double Average (this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int> source);` as you can see it works on `IEnumerable` and `list` implement it.

Comment: And PaulF used the `public static double Average<TSource> (this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource,int> selector);` overload that is the same [reference Code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,2101)

Comment: @PaulF, that should make no diff as it's just a `Enumerable.Average(Enumerable.Select(source, selector))`, but I will have to check the IL to be sure.

Comment: Since you're running the .Average against a List, EF isn't needed, just Linq

Comment: @DragandDrop: I would expect that to be the case - just highlighting another option

Answer (score 0):

best way this :
first read all and add to a list then do other operation on list

here it is a sample!

```
sing System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                employees.Add(new Employee
                {
                    Name ="name "+i,
                    Function = "fun "+i,
                    Age =i+24,
                    Salary =100+i,
                    Studies ="stu"+i
                });
            }



            //here can do any opr on list
            double avg =employees.Average(s => s.Salary);
            var result = employees.Where(x => x.Age > 25 && x.Age < 35 && x.Salary> avg).ToList();

            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("item name:" + item.Name);

            }

            Console.WriteLine("avg :" + avg);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }


        public class Employee
        {
            public string Name { set; get; }
            public string Function { set; get; }
            public int Salary { set; get; }
            public int Age { set; get; }
            public string Studies { set; get; }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I might be missing something here, but other than defining the Employee class isn't this identical to the answer by AlleXyS? (You are missing a greater than operator for the average check BTW)